# Show ErrorMessage in an own model property

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I've created my own model property, which says "ErrorMessage could not be found":

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
[StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Email too large.")]
[RegularExpressionTimeOut(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)@(outlook|hotmail|yahoo)\.\w{2,}$", 5), 
                         ErrorMessage = "Invalid email."] // 5 seconds
public string Email { get; set; }
```

And the class of this property:

```
public class RegularExpressionTimeOut : 
                             System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute
{
    public System.TimeSpan TimeOut { get; set; }
    public string Pattern { get; set; }
    //public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    //new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pattern">Regular expression as string</param>
    /// <param name="timeOut">Number of seconds</param>
    public RegularExpressionTimeOut(string pattern, int timeOut)
    {
        this.Pattern = pattern;
        this.TimeOut = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, timeOut);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ErrorMessage) && ...)

        return (new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(this.Pattern, 
                      System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None, this.TimeOut))
          .IsMatch(this.Pattern);
    }
}
```

Then, the question is, how can I show the ErrorMessage?

**Updated with the FormatErrorMessage**
My web don't show the error message anyway.

```
public class RegularExpressionTimeOut : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute
{
    public System.TimeSpan TimeOut { get; set; }
    public string Pattern { get; set; }
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "Invalid email.";
    //private string ErrorMessage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pattern">Regular expression as string</param>
    /// <param name="timeOut">Number of seconds</param>
    public RegularExpressionTimeOut(string pattern, int timeOut) : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        this.Pattern = pattern;
        this.TimeOut = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, timeOut);
        //this.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ErrorMessage) && ...)

        return (new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(this.Pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None, this.TimeOut)).IsMatch(this.Pattern);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string ErrorMessage)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You `RegularExpressionTimeOut` constructor does not have a parameter for `ErrorMessage`. The typical usage is

```
public class RegularExpressionTimeOut : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "Invalid email";

    public RegularExpressionTimeOut(string pattern, int timeOut) : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
```

and usually an override is added to format a specific message provide in the `Attribute` where you access values such as the property name (although in your case you don't seem to be needing or wanting that.

```
public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
{
    return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, .....);
}
```

Side note: your closing parenthesis is not located correctly. It should be

```
[RegularExpressionTimeOut(@"....", 5, ErrorMessage = "Invalid email.")]
```

**Edit**

Your not actually testing the value of the `Email` property which is posted back (you just testing that the regex pattern matches itself. You need to change the `IsValid()` method to

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    string email = (string)value; // cast it to a string for use in the Regex method
    return (new Regex(this.Pattern, RegexOptions.None, this.TimeOut)).IsMatch(email);
}
```

Note also that the regex pattern you have shown should take a few millisecond to test so its not clear why you would need this. In addition, you do not have any associated client side validation (your attribute does not implement `ICientValitable` and in any case there would be no point since javascript regex does not have a timeout) so the message would only be returned if you return the view when `ModelState.IsValid == false`. In that case, your message *"Invalid email"* would be rather confusing to the user and it should probably indicate that it needs to be *@outlook* or *@hotmail* etc.

Comment: "DefaultErrorMessage does not existe in the current context". And why declase DefaultErrorMessage as constant if I must assign it a value in the constructor?

Comment: How can it not exist - its defined in the first line of the code I gave you - `private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "Invalid email";`!

Comment: Also, you have you closing parenthesis in the wrong place - it would need to be `[RegularExpressionTimeOut(@"....", 5, ErrorMessage = "Invalid email.")]`

Comment: Yes, it was my fault. I've updated my post because the error isn't printed anyway. See the last code, please.

Comment: But your updated code still does not use `: base("Some error message")` so the error message is never added (in my answer I suggested a constant but you could just hard code it if you want )

Comment: Ah, the default error is obligatory. Ok, sorry. I've re-updated because the message error isn't shown anyway.

Comment: Have you fixed the error with the incorrect parenthesis?

Comment: Of course. [RegularExpressionTimeOut(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)@(outlook|hotmail|yahoo)\.\w{2,}$", 5, ErrorMessage = "Invalid email.")]

Comment: I've tested returning all times false and I don't receive the error in the web. However, if I use the standard property [RegularExpression], it's shown.

Comment: Your code does not ever access the value of the property (as returned by `public override bool IsValid(object value)` so I'm not really sure what you actually testing - there would never be anything which is invalid.

Comment: You would need to (1) cast `value` to `string` (2) check its not `null` and (3) use `.....IsMatch(value);` - all you currently doing is check that the pattern matches the pattern

Comment: Note also in you case, your not really formatting anything so the `public override string FormatErrorMessage(string ErrorMessage)` is a bit pointless - its used when you have a default message such as `"The {0} field is required"` where you format the placeholder.

Comment: I don't understand. What variable should I cast its value to string?

Comment: No, that fine. Its just that your not actually testing anything. In the `IsValid(object value)` method, the value of the text the user entered in the textbox is passed to the method (put a breakpoint on the method and see the value of `value`) but you never use it - your not testing anything. But it any case, the pattern you have shown would take a few milliseconds so not really sure what the point of all this is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76844/discussion-between-joe-and-stephen-muecke).